# Accessing a Panatone Huey via Python

Tags: python, colors, usb, device-driver

I have a Panatone Huey, a monitor calibration probe (device you attach to the monitor, and it gives you colour readings) - I want to get readings from the device in Python.

Having never written such a device driver before, I'm not sure where to start.

I've found are two open-source C/C++ projects that interface with the Heuy - [ArgyllCMS](http://www.argyllcms.com/) and [mcalib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcalib/).

ArgyllCMS comes with a `spotread` command which returns readings from the device, although it only functions as an interactive command line tool, so running it via `subprocess` will not (easily) work.

The code ArgyllCMS uses to communicate with the device is in [spectro/huey.c](http://github.com/hughsie/hargyllcms/blob/master/spectro/huey.c)

Not tried it (only just found it while writing this question), but mcalib contains much less code, mainly just [heuy.cpp](http://mcalib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mcalib/huey.cpp?revision=1&view=markup) - however it has a worrying number of `FIXME` comments and incomplete methods, and the code appears to have been automatically generated (unhelpful variable names)

There seems to be three options:

- Modify `spotread` to work without any interactive prompts, call it via `subprocess`
- Create a C-based Python module around `huey.c` or `huey.cpp`
- Re-implement the interface using something like [PyUSB](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html)

Being much more familiar with Python, I'm tempted to use PyUSB, but will this be substantially more work than wrapping existing code with the Python C API? Is there anything obvious in either of the C implementations that will not be easily doable in PyUSB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the existence of `spotread` the easiest (though perhaps not the best) way to proceed would be to use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html). It allows you to interact with other command-line programs.

Comment: Ended up using pexpect, works perfectly for what I need. [The code is on Github](https://github.com/dbr/colourstuff/blob/79a477a610121039ebd814ef8944241c6179133b/lib/python/colourstuff/pyspotread.py#L161)